# Send a random value to an input element using for loop Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

So I'm testing a calculator. And I enter a numbers with a webdriver
Each element has a corresponding text value. I try to provide this value to xpath selector

I have a random number generator.
For example we have a number 256. Now have to send 3 times request with '2' then '5' and then '6'. So my logic was to create a list from a number and go through that list each time send a value that correspond to list index. Have no luck with that.

```
    def test_something(self):
    a = randint(0,9999)
    two_digits = map(int, str(a))
    def sum_list(a):
        for x in two_digits:
            a=x   
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value={}]").format(a).click()


    sum_list(two_digits)
```

So I tried couple of options, tried to send x value to the string. Returned not a valid XPath expression. also tried to send it as element with specific index

```
i = 0
("//input[@value={}]").format(two_digits[i])
i += 1
```

Have not figure out yet. So what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

As you provided, the problem is in xPath. `//input[@value={}]` is not a valid xPath. I think you want something like `//input[@value='a']`. Try this:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='" + str(a) + "']").click()
```

lets say `a = 5`, then:

`//input[@value= '5']` is a valid `xPath`

PS: I don't know what `.format(a)` does. Make sure, that you need this method.

Comment: .format(a) - it is a simple python function for a string to pass an argument to a string where {} define where this argument would be passed

Comment: Then there is no need in it :). Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Here the proper solution. First have to create a list from random number and go through each number (like push dial numbers on a phone)

```
a = randint(0,99999)
    # Put in a list random number for exaple 124 will be [1,2,4]
    list = [int(d) for d in str(a)]
    # Go through the list where number of iterations is equal to number of elements
    # Each iteration send value of this element to xpath
    for item in list:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value={0}]".format(item)).click()
```